Question on tangent planes and normal lines

PFA the question I am looking at. For this one, I computed that the point P is $(1,1,1)$. Then I find the gradient to the surface and compute it at $(1,1,1)$ which gives me the normal vector to the surface as $<1,1,4>$.
After this, I find an equation that describes the curve $r(t)$ which is $z=\frac{x}{y}$. Then, I find the gradient to this at P as $<-1,1,1>$. The angle between the two gradients computed here should be the angle between the curve and the surface but the answer I get from this isn't the right answer. Could anyone explain what I did wrong?

The tangent vector is $\frac{dr}{dt}$ at the value $t=1$ you found.

Right, I could use the tangent vector at $\frac{dr}{dt}$ but why is this approach incorrect?

$z=\frac{x}{y}$ is a surface in 3 dimensions, you need two implicit equations to define a curve.

oh I see. How would I combine two implicit equations to make a curve?

.You could just as easily say that $x=y^3$ for your curve or some other relation between the variables. Not sure how helpful that is though. Much easier to use the fact that a normal vector to a curve is the derivative of the tangent vector
